# What does the sentence "When you swipe your card at the checkout line, you'll be asked if you want to pay by debit or credit." mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found this as an example sentence using the word "debit"; and I understand its grammar and everything, but I have no idea what "paying by credit" or "paying by debit" mean.

Another sentence example for the word "debit" was "I had lost the original invoice but I still had the debit receipt."; and once again, I have no idea what is meant by "debit receipt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **debit card** is used to take the money directly from your bank account. So when you "pay by debit" it means you use a **debit card** to pay.

A **credit card** is used to take the money from the card provider *first*, who then bills you for the amount, which you pay *later*. So when you "pay by credit" it means you use a **credit card** to pay.

The **receipt** is a piece of paper which confirms the transaction. It usually gives the date & time, the business name, the amount, and states "cash" or an abbreviated description of the card used. So you are given a **cash receipt**, a **debit receipt**, or a **credit receipt**.

Often you will be given an invoice as well as a **debit receipt** (or **credit receipt**). But if you lose the invoice, the payment receipt on its own might be good enough as "proof of purchase".

---

The scenario in the question title does not usually happen, since the card itself identifies whether it is a credit or debit card. But some companies might not accept payment by credit card - only by debit card - and might want to know in advance.

Comment: "But some companies might not accept payment by credit card." Is that true in America? I can't think of any company that only accepts debit cards in the UK. On the other hand, the sentence is written in American English, so the UK is probably irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: @JamesK it is quite common for corporate credit cards to be refused (in UK). I was surmising about the title question.

Comment: I understand that in the USA it's possible for a bank card to have more than one account associated with it, so it's possible to choose between credit or debit (or current / checking account and savings account) when you use it. In the UK it's one account, one card, and UK cash machines (or shop card payment terminals) don't let you choose which account the money comes out of.

Comment: @Owain I see, thank you.